# Page not found (404) Using the URLconf defined in project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, django-urls

In my rest API, I have added some data to table userdetails through http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/eatslushapp/userdetails/add/

but when I click the http://127.0.0.1:8000/userdetails I am getting the following result in my browser

Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Using the URLconf defined in eatslush.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^admin/
^userdetails/
The empty path didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

I tried this by watching this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ejJ-2oz4AgI

NB:The admin url works fine

The following is my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
from eatslushapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^userdetails/', views.userdetailsList.as_view()),

]
```

The following is settings.py

```
    """
    Django settings for eatslush project.

    Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.11.18.

    For more information on this file, see
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/settings/

    For the full list of settings and their values, see
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/
    """

    import os

    # Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


    # Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
    # See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

    # SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
    SECRET_KEY = '@3=r$utcg(megzsn*6v#(&2ib@78xgfmij8086x^4ec4_6k08*'

    # SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
    DEBUG = True

    ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


    # Application definition

    INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'rest_framework',
        'eatslushapp',

    ]

    MIDDLEWARE = [
        'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    ]

    ROOT_URLCONF = 'eatslush.urls'

    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]

    WSGI_APPLICATION = 'eatslush.wsgi.application'


    # Database
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        }
    }


    # Password validation
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

    AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
        },
        {
            'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
        },
    ]


    # Internationalization
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

    LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

    TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

    USE_I18N = True

    USE_L10N = True

    USE_TZ = True


    # Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

following is my serializer.py
        from rest_framework import serializers
        from models import userdetails

```
    class user_detailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = userdetails
            #        fields =('name',)
            fields = '_all_',
```

following is views.py

## -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from .models import userdetails
from .serializers import user_detailsSerializer


class userdetailsList(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        user1 = userdetails.objects.all()
        serializer = user_detailsSerializer(user1, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self):
        pass
```

models.py

## -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models


class userdetails(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    profile_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=15)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

admin.py

## -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from . models import userdetails
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.register(userdetails)
```

I just want to get my data in json format

Comment: Did you post the correct urlpatterns? In your screenshot the user details url has `^$` in the beginning...

Comment: @BernhardVallant tried with $ and without $,no changes in results

Comment: make sure you have your app added in your `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: Also, try using `url(r'^userdetails/$', views.userdetailsList.as_view()),`, notice the `$`

Comment: The `urlpatterns` would not give the error with `^$^userdetails/`. Either you have another `urls.py` that you haven't included in your question, or you need to save your current `urls.py` and restart `manage.py runserver` so that you are running the code you think you are.

Comment: Please don't copy and paste screenshots of code and error messages. Copy and paste the text instead.

Comment: @Shinratensei  I have updated the code, please see

Comment: and I dont have another urls.py file and tried url(r'^userdetails/$', views.userdetailsList.as_view()),.still same result

Answer (score 2):

you need the trailing slash on the url you're asking the browser for

http://127.0.0.1:8000/userdetails/

note the trailing slash

Comment: when I do that I am getting "no such table: eatslushapp_userdetails"

Comment: that then suggests you haven't run migrations

Comment: shows django.db.utils.DatabaseError: database disk image is malformed

Comment: that's an entirely different issue than what your original question covers.  I'd suggest you look in the documentation for your database for how to resolve this new issue

Comment: when I open the sqlite file all i can see is a lot of squares,and I tried to open it with other online tools and it saying diskimage is malformed

Comment: I think you should erase all your db data and rerun your project